# How this inherience case is solved based on Islamic laws?

Tags: sharia, inheritance

Lets assume a man is dead and his left relatives are his wife, his parents and 3 daughters and after paying all debts and costs of funeral and any other payable amounts before dividing, finally there remains 1,000,000 $. How much is the share of any of the remained relatives?

*(Only the final solution is not purpose of this question. instead solution including the verses and authentic hadith used is the main purpose of this question.)*

Comment: Quran[4:11, 4:12 and 4:176] thats what you want isn't it?

Comment: Definitely an interesting question. I dropped out just because of the last requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you inquired an interesting inquiry. There are some verses which speaking regarding inheritance. E.g. Surah Nisa(4) verses 11-12; likewise 4:176

For instance look at the verse below:

> يُوصِيكُمُ اللَّـهُ فِي أَوْلَادِكُمْ ۖ لِلذَّكَرِ مِثْلُ حَظِّ
>   الْأُنثَيَيْنِ ۚ فَإِن كُنَّ نِسَاءً فَوْقَ اثْنَتَيْنِ فَلَهُنَّ
>   ثُلُثَا مَا تَرَكَ ۖ وَإِن كَانَتْ وَاحِدَةً فَلَهَا النِّصْفُ ۚ
>   وَلِأَبَوَيْهِ لِكُلِّ وَاحِدٍ مِّنْهُمَا السُّدُسُ مِمَّا تَرَكَ إِن
>   كَانَ لَهُ وَلَدٌ ۚ فَإِن لَّمْ يَكُن لَّهُ وَلَدٌ وَوَرِثَهُ
>   أَبَوَاهُ فَلِأُمِّهِ الثُّلُثُ ۚ فَإِن كَانَ لَهُ إِخْوَةٌ
>   فَلِأُمِّهِ السُّدُسُ ۚ مِن بَعْدِ وَصِيَّةٍ يُوصِي بِهَا أَوْ دَيْنٍ
>   ۗ آبَاؤُكُمْ وَأَبْنَاؤُكُمْ لَا تَدْرُونَ أَيُّهُمْ أَقْرَبُ لَكُمْ
>   نَفْعًا ۚ فَرِيضَةً مِّنَ اللَّـهِ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ كَانَ عَلِيمًا
>   حَكِيمًا ﴿١١﴾
>
> Allah instructs you concerning your children: for the male, what is
>   equal to the share of two females. But if there are [only] daughters,
>   two or more, for them is two thirds of one's estate. And if there is
>   only one, for her is half. And for one's parents, to each one of them
>   is a sixth of his estate if he left children. But if he had no
>   children and the parents [alone] inherit from him, then for his mother
>   is one third. And if he had brothers [or sisters], for his mother is a
>   sixth, after any bequest he [may have] made or debt. Your parents or
>   your children - you know not which of them are nearest to you in
>   benefit. [These shares are] an obligation [imposed] by Allah. Indeed,
>   Allah is ever Knowing and Wise. (11)
>
> وَلَكُمْ نِصْفُ مَا تَرَكَ أَزْوَاجُكُمْ إِن لَّمْ يَكُن لَّهُنَّ
>   وَلَدٌ ۚ فَإِن كَانَ لَهُنَّ وَلَدٌ فَلَكُمُ الرُّبُعُ مِمَّا تَرَكْنَ
>   ۚ مِن بَعْدِ وَصِيَّةٍ يُوصِينَ بِهَا أَوْ دَيْنٍ ۚ وَلَهُنَّ
>   الرُّبُعُ مِمَّا تَرَكْتُمْ إِن لَّمْ يَكُن لَّكُمْ وَلَدٌ ۚ فَإِن
>   كَانَ لَكُمْ وَلَدٌ فَلَهُنَّ الثُّمُنُ مِمَّا تَرَكْتُم ۚ مِّن بَعْدِ
>   وَصِيَّةٍ تُوصُونَ بِهَا أَوْ دَيْنٍ ۗ وَإِن كَانَ رَجُلٌ يُورَثُ
>   كَلَالَةً أَوِ امْرَأَةٌ وَلَهُ أَخٌ أَوْ أُخْتٌ فَلِكُلِّ وَاحِدٍ
>   مِّنْهُمَا السُّدُسُ ۚ فَإِن كَانُوا أَكْثَرَ مِن ذَٰلِكَ فَهُمْ
>   شُرَكَاءُ فِي الثُّلُثِ ۚ مِن بَعْدِ وَصِيَّةٍ يُوصَىٰ بِهَا أَوْ
>   دَيْنٍ غَيْرَ مُضَارٍّ ۚ وَصِيَّةً مِّنَ اللَّـهِ ۗ وَاللَّـهُ عَلِيمٌ
>   حَلِيمٌ ﴿١٢﴾
>
> And for you is half of what your wives leave if they have no child.
>   But if they have a child, for you is one fourth of what they leave,
>   after any bequest they [may have] made or debt. And for the wives is
>   one fourth if you leave no child. But if you leave a child, then for
>   them is an eighth of what you leave, after any bequest you [may have]
>   made or debt. And if a man or woman leaves neither ascendants nor
>   descendants but has a brother or a sister, then for each one of them
>   is a sixth. But if they are more than two, they share a third, after
>   any bequest which was made or debt, as long as there is no detriment
>   [caused]. [This is] an ordinance from Allah, and Allah is Knowing and
>   Forbearing. (12)

Consequently, according to the above-mentioned verses it could be inferred that the shares of them are as shown in below:

- Daughters: 2/3
- Parents: 1/3
- Wife: 1/8

**References:**

http://tanzil.net/#4:12

Comment: That can't be it. It comes put to more than 100%.

Comment: Distribute the $ in the order the people are listed. Daughters get no less than 2/3. Parents no less than 1/9 (1/3 * the remaining). Wife no less than 2/72 (1/8 * 2/9 that remain). 58/72 have been assigned by this directive, the rest can be divided any which way. (that is how I would follow this rule in this case)

Comment: @mate, we should notice that the Quran mentions many matters in general (not in details). So it mentioned the general formula of it. but in solving in specific issues, there are some tafseers and solution (according to Shia, in accordance with the narrations..). You'd better to refer to the sites below (in Farsi) to see the solution of the mentioned matter. http://shobheha2.blogfa.com/post-19.aspx  

http://shobheha2.blogfa.com/cat-11.aspx